# Calling the method "buildRoadOverlay" correctly

Tags: java, android, methods, osmdroid

I want to call the method `buildRoadOverlay` (Method is on the bottom of this post) from OSMdroid. How do I set the parameters correctly?

This method builds a route on a map between two waypoints. It works, as long as I leave out color and width when calling the method. Now I want the color to be green and the width to be 20dp.

This is how I tried it:

```
Polyline roadOverlay = RoadManager.buildRoadOverlay(road, 7667507, 20);
```

The app starts, no errors, but the Line RoadOverlay does not get drawn anymore. Either that or it is invisible. I am not sure.

The method I want to call:

```
public static Polyline buildRoadOverlay(Road road, int color, float width){
        Polyline roadOverlay = new Polyline();
        roadOverlay.setColor(color);
        roadOverlay.setWidth(width);
        if (road != null) {
            ArrayList<GeoPoint> polyline = road.mRouteHigh;
            roadOverlay.setPoints(polyline);
        }
        return roadOverlay;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

color is an [Android Color](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html). width is a float, in pixels. So try:

```
Polyline roadOverlay = RoadManager.buildRoadOverlay(road, Color.GREEN, 20.0f);
```

Putting some transparency on road shape is recommended, so that street names for instance remain visible. So this will be better:

```
Polyline roadOverlay = RoadManager.buildRoadOverlay(road, 0x8000FF00, 20.0f);
```

(and yes, I apologize for the javadoc of this method. I will improve it)